# Prove a restriction of a one to one function is one to one

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I know the question is intuitive, but I don't know how to formally proof it.

So, so far I have written down:

Define [a,b] as the restriction of a one-to-one function f. Because f is a one-to-one function and by definition for x,y, f(x)=f(y) => x=y,....

Can someone guide me on this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f\colon S\to T$ is one-to-one. Then for any $x,y\in T$, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$.

Now let $\tilde f\colon R\to U$ be a restriction of $f$, where $R\subseteq S$ and $U\subseteq T$. Then for any $x,y\in U$, we know that $x,y$ are also in $T$, and so $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$